# emacs: Orgmode, how to make a list from a block of lines

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to covert such block of lines

```
line1  
line2 
linen
```

into

```
1. line1
2. line2
n. linen
```

Using Emacs [org mode](http://orgmode.org)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

don't know if there is a direct way, haven't heard of it yet at least. But one approach would be to use `string-rectangle` (`C-x r t`) to prepand `1.` to all lines and then hit `C-c C-c` to update the numbering.

For `string-rectangle` you would put point and mark the following way:

```
v---mark
line1 with some text
line2 with more text
<---point
```

After `M-x: string-rectangle: 1.` you will get:

```
1. line1 with some text
1. line2 with more text
```

Hitting `C-c C-c` will give you the correct numbering!

Easier because it gives you visual feedback is to enable [`CUA-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode) and use `C-return` to create a rectangle selection, then you can start typing on all lines in parallel. See also [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGLjkZxaFkw) on youtube.

Comment: [Make sure you check out CUA rectangles (like described on emacs-fu)](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2010/01/rectangles-and-cua.html), they are a lot nicer to work with than vanilla rectangles. But using rectangles for the problem above is the best working solution :)

Answer (score 47):

the shortest way I know of is: highlight the lines, including their newline character,

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Then execute `M-x org-ctrl-c-minus` (press `C-c -`) and you will get

```
- line1  
- line2 
- line3
```

Then run `M-x org-shiftright` (press `<S-right>`) twice and you get the desired

```
1. line1  
2. line2 
3. line3
```

Comment: When I do `C-c -`, it only inserts `-` on the first line, the following lines are just indented.

Comment: Select the region before pressing `C-c -`.

Comment: With org 7.8.06, `C-c -` on the selected region only inserts the `-` on the first line. The version of org I was using previously must have behaved differently because of my comment above.

Comment: Use `C-u C-c -` to insert a `-` at the start of each line in the selected region. From the org help in Emacs: "If it is normal text, change region into an item.  With a prefix argument ARG, change each line in region into an item."

Answer (score 6):

See also `org-toggle-item` to convert to plain-text list or numbered list.

Comment: Only gives me an [_Unordered_ List](https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html). Still useful, though.

Comment: True, but then from there (now an unordered list), with cursor on any one of the lines, use `C-c -` to cycle through to the other list types

Answer (score 2):

Found this on emacsworld.blogspot.com (I made some minor edits):

In Emacs 24.1, the NEWS file had this new addition to the rectangle commands.

> ** New command `C-x r N' (`rectangle-number-lines') numbers the lines in the current rectangle.  With a prefix argument, this prompts for a
>   number to count from and for a format string.

This allows you to now number lines or lists easily without using a macro or additional elisp functions.  Mark a vertical region of text (using transient mark mode may help), 1 character wide, and then hit C-x r N and that's it.  Emacs numbers the lines.

If you use the prefix command C-u (for example, C-u C-x r N), it will prompt you for a starting digit and the format string, so you can start at an arbitrary number and specify a period or paren or whatever to precede or follow the number.