# Turn region into list

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Org-mode I want to a region into a list.

Say that I have the following text

```
One
Two
Three
```

How can I turn it into the following list (except by manually editing it)?

```
- One
- Two
- Three
```

Is there some command I can run to achieve that after I have marked the region?

Comment: You can use Emacs' regex engine to replace `^` with `- ` on the region -- but I don't know the command for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [emacs: Orgmode, how to make a list from a block of lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250930/emacs-orgmode-how-to-make-a-list-from-a-block-of-lines)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of ways. Here are a few:

1. `query-replace-regexp`: Either mark the region, or just move point to the beginning of line 1, then use <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> `^` <kbd>RET</kbd> `-` <kbd>RET</kbd>. If you marked the region, you could use <kbd>!</kbd> to replace all matches in the region.
2. `string-rectangle`: Set the mark at the beginning of line 1, move point to the beginning of line 3, type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> `-` <kbd>RET</kbd>
3. `cua-selection-mode`: If you enable cua-selection-mode (I turn this on in my .emacs), you can activate a rectangle at the beginning of line 1 with <kbd>C-RET</kbd>, move point down to the beginning of line 3, type `-`, and then type <kbd>C-RET</kbd> again to deactivate the rectangle.
4. Keyboard macros: On line 1, type <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> to start recording, then <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> as the content of the macro, and <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> to stop recording. Now you can mark the region and type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> to apply that macro to each line in the region.
5. (edit) I somehow missed that this was about org-mode, which makes this a duplicate of [emacs: Orgmode, how to make a list from a block of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250930/emacs-orgmode-how-to-make-a-list-from-a-block-of-lines) (see [gregor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3850846/324105)).

Comment: The last choice (5) is probably the best one for org-mode.  `C-c -` (Ctrl-C minus) should transform the lines into a list.  I have on occasion had the first item object that it isn't a list item, at worst you may have to manually change it and then the rest should follow properly (And I'm not entirely sure why it fails at times but not others).